# Xamarin.UITest - Marked

Tags: xamarin, ui-automation, xamarin.uitest

I am writing automation tests using Xamarin.UITest. I have started adding Automation Ids to the Xaml files of the Xamarin project. I am wondering if there is increased efficiency in the tests by using Automation Id's over the Text within the UI Element?

What I have tried to figure out is if there is a order in which the Marked method performs a search of the UI tree. I decompiled the Xamarin.UITest to see what was specified in the Queries.Marked method.

It states in the method what it searches for on Android and iOS but it's not clear to me how this is achieved.

Has anyone got any knowledge on this?

```
/// <summary>
/// Matches common values.
/// For Android: An element with the given value as either <c>id</c>, <c>contentDescription</c> or <c>text</c>.
/// For iOS: An element with the given value as either <c>accessibilityLabel</c> or <c>accessibilityIdentifier</c>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">The value to match.</param>
public AppQuery Marked(string text)
{
  AppQuery appQuery = this;
  if (!((IEnumerable<IQueryToken>) this._tokens).Any<IQueryToken>())
    appQuery = new AppQuery(appQuery, new object[1]
    {
      (object) new HiddenToken("*")
    });
  return new AppQuery(appQuery, new object[1]
  {
    (object) new WrappingToken((IQueryToken) new StringPropertyToken<SingleQuoteEscapedString>("marked", new SingleQuoteEscapedString(text)), string.Format("Marked(\"{0}\")", (object) text))
  });
}
```

[image: Marked Method]

Comment: Maybe you can search some info about [Xamarin.UITest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/appcenter/test-cloud/frameworks/uitest/#introducing-the-xamarinuitest-api)

Comment: Thank you @CherryBu-MSFT . I have read that documentation. It's a good guide on what how to use the Marked method but it's doesn't give in depth detail on the algorithm used.

Comment: not search some detailed info about uitest depth detail on the algorithm used, if you still don't see any document about this, you can feedback this problem at gtihub.